# Pretrained InceptionV3 - very low accuracy on Tobacco dataset

Tags: keras, inception

I'm trying to fine-tune a pre-trained InceptionV3 on the [tobacco-3482 document dataset](https://lampsrv02.umiacs.umd.edu/projdb/project.php?id=72) (I'm only using the first 6 classes), but I'm getting accuracies under 20% on the validation set (> 90% accuracy on the training set). I've tried numerous batch sizes, epochs, etc., any ideas? Here is my code for Keras:

```
import sys
import os
from keras.layers import *
from keras.optimizers import *
from keras.applications import *
from keras.models import Model
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
from keras import backend as k
import keras
import glob

def get_nb_files(directory):
  """Get number of files by searching directory recursively"""
  if not os.path.exists(directory):
    return 0
  cnt = 0
  for r, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for dr in dirs:
      cnt += len(glob.glob(os.path.join(r, dr + "/*")))
  return cnt

# fix seed for reproducible results (only works on CPU, not GPU)
seed = 9
np.random.seed(seed=seed)
tf.set_random_seed(seed=seed)

# hyper parameters for model
nb_classes = 6  # number of classes
based_model_last_block_layer_number = 126  # value is based on based model selected.
img_width, img_height = 299, 299  # change based on the shape/structure of your images
batch_size = 32  # try 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256 dependent on CPU/GPU memory capacity (powers of 2 values).
nb_epoch = 50  # number of iteration the algorithm gets trained.
learn_rate = 1e-4  # sgd learning rate
momentum = .9  # sgd momentum to avoid local minimum
transformation_ratio = 0  # how aggressive will be the data augmentation/transformation
nb_train_samples = get_nb_files('tobacco')  # Total number of train samples. NOT including augmented images
nb_validation_samples = get_nb_files('tobacco-test')  # Total number of train samples. NOT including augmented images.


def train(train_data_dir, validation_data_dir, model_path):
    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
        input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
    else:
        input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

    base_model = InceptionV3(input_shape=input_shape, weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

    x = base_model.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    x = Dense(256, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

    predictions = Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)

    # add your top layer block to your base model
    model = Model(base_model.input, predictions)
    print(model.summary())


    # first: train only the top layers (which were randomly initialized)
    # i.e. freeze all layers of the based model that is already pre-trained.
    for layer in base_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    # Read Data and Augment it: Make sure to select augmentations that are appropriate to your images.
    # To save augmentations un-comment save lines and add to your flow parameters.
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255,
                                       rotation_range=transformation_ratio,
                                       shear_range=transformation_ratio,
                                       zoom_range=transformation_ratio,
                                       cval=transformation_ratio,
                                       horizontal_flip=False,
                                       vertical_flip=False)

    validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir,
                                                        target_size=[img_width, img_height],
                                                        batch_size=batch_size,
                                                        class_mode='categorical')

    validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_data_dir,
                                                                  target_size=[img_width, img_height],
                                                                  batch_size=batch_size,
                                                                  class_mode='categorical')

    model.compile(optimizer='nadam',
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',  # categorical_crossentropy if multi-class classifier
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    # save weights of best training epoch: monitor either val_loss or val_acc

    top_weights_path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(model_path), 'top_model_weights.h5')
    callbacks_list = [
        ModelCheckpoint(top_weights_path, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True),
        EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', patience=5, verbose=0),
        keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='tensorboard/inception-v3-train-top-layer', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=False, write_images=False)
    ]

    # Train Simple CNN
    model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                        steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
                        epochs=nb_epoch / 5,
                        validation_data=validation_generator,
                        validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size,
                        callbacks=callbacks_list,
                        verbose=1)

    # verbose
    print("\nStarting to Fine Tune Model\n")

    # add the best weights from the train top model
    model.load_weights(top_weights_path)

    for layer in model.layers[:based_model_last_block_layer_number]:
        layer.trainable = False
    for layer in model.layers[based_model_last_block_layer_number:]:
        layer.trainable = True

    # compile the model with a SGD/momentum optimizer
    # and a very slow learning rate.
    model.compile(optimizer='nadam',
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    # save weights of best training epoch: monitor either val_loss or val_acc
    final_weights_path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(model_path), 'model_weights.h5')
    callbacks_list = [
        ModelCheckpoint(final_weights_path, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True),
        EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5, verbose=0),
        keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='tensorboard/inception-v3-fine-tune', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=False, write_images=False)
    ]

    # fine-tune the model
    model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                        steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
                        epochs=nb_epoch,
                        validation_data=validation_generator,
                        validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size,
                        callbacks=callbacks_list,
                        verbose=1)

    # save model
    model_json = model.to_json()
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(model_path), 'model.json'), 'w') as json_file:
        json_file.write(model_json)


train('tobacco', 'tobacco-test', '.')
```

Comment: Turns out switching to a VGG16 model improved acc to 76%. What makes VGG a better model for document image classification?